# Multiple RadioButtonLists and Inserting into SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am creating a survey page using ASP.NET. It has 29 questions over radiobuttonlist (answers) and is currently stored by row.

Original:

```
EmpID | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | ---> Q29
123   | 1  | 3  | 5  |
```

The original data works using one insert clause.

```
insert into response table (empid,q1,q2,q3 etc) values (@empid,@q1,@q2,@q3)
```

I would like to store the results like:

```
EmpID | QNum | Result
123 | Q1 | 1
123 | Q2 | 3
123 | Q3 | 5
```

Would I need to create separate insert SQL clauses or can I loop the SQL to automate it?

I dont mind writing multiple inserts but it looks pretty inefficient.

```
insert into response table (empid,QNum,result) values (@empid, 'Q1', @q1)
insert into response table (empid,QNum,result) values (@empid, 'Q2', @q2)
etc etc
```

Regards,

Neil

Comment: There is a code review area for this type of questions: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MS SQL server, you should be able to use the [UNPIVOT function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Perhaps something like this might work?

```
insert into response_table (empid, QNum, Result)
select empid,QNum,result
from (select @empid,@q1,@q2,@q3) p
UNPIVOT
(Result for QNum in ('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3') ) as unpvt;
```

There is a similar function in Oracle as well.

Unfortunately there isn't one for MySQL.

Comment: ahh so capture the data as I am already but pivot the result table?

Comment: You could do that too! Good luck.

Comment: not had a chance to try yet Midnight. Will let you know when I do.